# Error when trying to add one field based on two others being equal. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting errors when I'm trying to create a field basically saying incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE', which is ***'d.

Everything that isn't starred was existing and functioning. I just need to add the  starred stuff in a working fashion.

Essentially, I am adding a table `[ru_t_FDA Tracked Items]` that contains a list of `[Product Numbers]` that are essentially [CFN]s. The `[cc_tCC_Audit]` table is the central place where product information is existing and where the `[CFN]` resides.

The goal is to create a field called [FDA Inv] that, if [cc_tCC_Audit].CFN = [ru_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Number] then I will take the quantity [CC Qty] in [cc_tCC_Audit]

```
SELECT 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Area) AS Area, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Area Name]) AS [Area Name], 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Region) AS Region, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Region Name]) AS [Region Name], 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.District) AS District,
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[District Name]) AS [District Name], 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Territory) AS Territory, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Territory Name]) AS [Territory Name], 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Therapy, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Name,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Type,
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_Start_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_End_Date, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Template_Sent_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Received_Date, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Upload_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Type, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Master_Reconciled_Date, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Date_Discrepancies_Processed, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status, dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Value, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Comments, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Last_Updated_user,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1)
              THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) 
              ELSE 0 
        END) AS [SAP Inv],
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.Override_Value, rr.Serial_Lot_Flag) = 'S' AND (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1) 
              THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) 
              ELSE 0 
        END) AS [SAP Serial Inv],
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.Override_Value, rr.Serial_Lot_Flag) = 'L' AND (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1) 
              THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) 
              ELSE 0 
       END) AS [SAP Lot Inv]
    CASE 
        WHEN dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN = dbo.[ru_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Number] 
          THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[CC Qty], 0) 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS [FDA Inv]
FROM 
    dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Audit ON dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID = dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CCMasterID 
                     ON dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Code = dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride ON dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.CFN 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.[rt_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Name] ON dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN = dbo.[rt_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Name] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master ON dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Territory = dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Territory AND dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU ISNULL(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.BU,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU) 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Area ON dbo.cc_tCC_Area.CCArea = dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT AuditID, Serial_Lot_Flag FROM dbo.cc_tCC_ResearchResults) AS rr ON rr.AuditID = dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.AuditID
GROUP BY 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Therapy, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Name, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Type, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_Start_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_End_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Template_Sent_Date,
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Received_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Upload_Date, 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Type, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Master_Reconciled_Date,
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Date_Discrepancies_Processed, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status, 
    dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Value, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Comments,
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Last_Updated_user
```

Comment: You're missing comma at the end of the previous line, after you add that you'll probably get error about group by / the case not being in an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

Since the data in that final case is not aggregated, you would need to include it in your grouping.

```
    SELECT 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU, MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Area) AS Area, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Area Name]) AS [Area Name], 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Region) AS Region, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Region Name]) AS [Region Name], MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.District) AS District,
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[District Name]) AS [District Name], MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Territory) AS Territory, 
    MIN(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.[Territory Name]) AS [Territory Name], dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Therapy, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Name,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Type,
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_Start_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_End_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Template_Sent_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Received_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Upload_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Type, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Master_Reconciled_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Date_Discrepancies_Processed, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status, dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Value, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Comments, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Last_Updated_user,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1) THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [SAP Inv],
    SUM(CASE WHEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.Override_Value, rr.Serial_Lot_Flag) = 'S' AND (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1) THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [SAP Serial Inv],
    SUM(CASE WHEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.Override_Value, rr.Serial_Lot_Flag) = 'L' AND (isnull(LEFT(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.Plant, 1), 'x') <> 'Z' OR dbo.cc_tCC_Area.Count_Fixed_Assets = 1) THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[SAP Qty], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [SAP Lot Inv]
    CASE WHEN dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN = dbo.[ru_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Number] THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[CC Qty], 0) ELSE 0 END AS [FDA Inv]
    FROM dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes INNER JOIN dbo.cc_tCC_Master LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cc_tCC_Audit ON dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID = dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CCMasterID ON dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Code = dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride ON dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN dbo.cc_tCfnSerialLotOverride.CFN LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.[rt_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Name] ON dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN = dbo.[rt_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Name] LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master ON dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Territory = dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.Territory AND dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU ISNULL(dbo.cc_qAARDT_Master.BU,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU) INNER JOIN 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Area ON dbo.cc_tCC_Area.CCArea = dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT AuditID, Serial_Lot_Flag FROM dbo.cc_tCC_ResearchResults) AS rr ON rr.AuditID = dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.AuditID

    GROUP BY 
    dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CCMasterID, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.BU, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Therapy, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Name,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Location_Type, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_Start_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.CC_End_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Template_Sent_Date,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Received_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Upload_Date, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Scan_Type, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Master_Reconciled_Date,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Date_Discrepancies_Processed, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Status, dbo.cc_tStatus_Codes.Status_Value, dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Comments,dbo.cc_tCC_Master.Last_Updated_user,
    CASE WHEN dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.CFN = dbo.[ru_t_FDA Tracked Items].[Product Number] THEN isnull(dbo.cc_tCC_Audit.[CC Qty], 0) ELSE 0 END
```